# Is it wise to use \tensor for bold letters?

Tags: packages, bold, subscripts, superscripts, tensor

I want to use bold math-letters e.g. 
`\mathbf{p_1}^2`. The problem with `\mathbf{p_1}^2` is that the 1 and 2 sub/superscripts are not aligned under each other. I can fix this by writing 
`\mathbf{p_1^2}` but then both the sub and superscript appears bold, I only want one of them bold (the 1 in the subscript). So what is the best solution to this? Is it wise to use the `\tensor` package to do this (if possible), what if one has thousands of these in a book/article, wouldn't calling the tensor package for each of them make compiling extremely slow?

Comment: I think you should change the title of this question to something more relevant.  The question doesn't mention the `\tensor` command anywhere.

Comment: It did, it just wasn't highlighted, it is fixed now. But I agree, the title sucks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be sufficiently clean; the bold subscript is not really a subscript, but part of the name, so it's treated as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tens}{mo}
 {% #1 = variable name, #2 = subscript (optional)
  \mathbf{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{_\mathbf{#2}}%
 }

\begin{document}
$\tens{p}[1]^{2}$ and $\tens{p}^{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use `bm` (boldmath)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\( \bm{p_{1}}^2 \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm...then the p get kind of italized, cool. I have to think about this one for a minute.

Comment: Yeah. Not sure if that's what you're looking for, but I thought I'd throw it out there anyway. You could also incorporate this into the solution provided by @egreg, i.e., defining a new command.

Comment: Actually @erik, it is good that you did that, I might use it instead (or in the future). Thanks bro.